# Difference between のに and というのに

Tags: grammar, particles

I have already looked at [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3832/difference-between-noun%E3%81%AA-and-noun%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86) but it didn't really help my understanding. I have the following sentence:

> 家来たちがそれぞれ自分の荷物を持ち上げて帰る用意をしている**というのに**、彦一｛ひこいち｝はなにも入っていない風呂敷｛ふろしき｝をたたんでふところにしまいました。

My attempt at a translation is:

> Even though the retainers each picked up their own baggage and were preparing to return home,  彦一 folded up a *wrapping cloth* with nothing in it and put it away in his breast pocket.

I thought のに translated as "even though" but that doesn't seem to join the two clauses together in a convincing way. So I'm assuming the という part modifies のに in some way such that it makes more sense. Please help me understand the difference between のに and というのに. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers in that old thread do not satisfy me, either.

My suggestion for a better translation of the 「というのに」 part in your sentence would simply be "***while***".  I would not buy the dictionary definition of "even though" in this particular case.

The difference between 「のに」 and 「というのに」 is minimal in meaning and yet two-fold.

1) 「のに」 sounds more informal and it is used more often in speaking.

2) 「というのに」 gives slightly more emphasis to the preceding words than 「のに」 does.

Comment: I had to think about this for a while. The "while" in your translation is like the "while" in "While it is true that vegetables are healthy, I prefer to eat meat", rather then the "while" that expresses concurrent actions. At least it make sense for me to think of it this way. Thanks.